# Eclipse product: Export multiple versions of a product which has slight variations

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, product

This is a relatively open ended question so I wouldn't just mind being pointed in the right direction.

I have a *product* that uses the Eclipse workbench to allow users to program in a custom language. For this product, I will also have some minor UI and internal changes for a lighter version to be exported. For example, a full version of the product contains some extra views and menus, and behaves slightly differently (like when creating a new file) where as the ligher version does not contain a lot of view and has a couple of different more simplified ones.

I do not want to make a copy of my workspace and then have 2 separate workspaces for a full version and a lighter version as that will be difficult to maintain in the long run especially when there are changes in code relevant to both. I want to be able to export both, full and light versions of a product from a common workspace.

How can I go about this? Or where can I start looking?

The product is a collection of features and uses the Eclipse workbench as its base application.

I would like to clarify that I am asking how I could hide a view for the full or light version, as an example. I know in C#, we have options like #if. I have seen a lot of questions which refer to having 2 different versions of the same code, but nothing about how they could have 2 different versions of the same code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [the Eclipse RCP book](http://eclipsercp.org/) it really fully explains how to do this. And to do it you need a solid understanding of the concepts of Eclipse plugin, feature, product, fragment and a few other things.

Essentially you can segment your application in to multiple plugins (have a base plugin for example, and then another that provides additional functionality). Then you organize those plugins into features that are the collection of the functionality to be installed. The notion of a "product" in Eclipse has to do with the branding, so you would probably have two products, a lite and a full one. The products could have a branding plugin (where the product is actually declared).

This should get you started.

Comment: Actually, I do have the book; was there any chapter in particular that you were referring to? I was considering having some property that can be set to LITE or FULL and using for example, if statements conditioned on the property to enable/disable views.

Comment: My other concern with separating into another plugin is that I have license checks in my main plugin.

Comment: What you want to do is put the views in the plugin that  needs them, so have a lite and full plugin that has the different code for each. And have different plugin.xmls for each. As for the license checks, the lite plugin will always be required (since that will have the core functionality) so it can go in the one place, as the full plugin cannot be used by itself. You don't want to do it with a property, but with a feature configuration so that the full edition only gets the required plugins.

Comment: And you can ask if a plugin is installed using the `Platform.getBundle()` method. This can serve in the place of your property.

Comment: ok thank you for the inputs. Before I separate my plugins, I want to check all my options and I have read a bit about activities, so want to research that option. If that doesn't serve my purpose then I will accept your answer immediately.

Comment: I just realised that the separate plugins works for my own views etc but what about views like the Project Explorer and menus like Project, is it possible to control their visibility at all or do I need to work on an RCP?

Comment: It's very easy with the Project Explorer and the new wizards, you can just put the changes in your plugin.xml files for each plugin. Everything will dynamically work together; that's the whole point of the Project Explorer.

Comment: I meant that I would like to remove items related to any kind of Project, such File -> New... -> Project and the Project menu itself.

Comment: I would ask about the Project menu thing as a separate question or on the Eclipse RCP or Platform forum at eclipse.org. I don't know the answer to that one.