# What is the Eclipse equivalent of Visual Studio's build configurations?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-ndk

I'm porting some Windows code to Android.

The Visual Studio project has various different build configurations for different versions of the application, (e.g. full version vs. demo).

What is the standard way to achieve this in Eclipse? The vast majority of the code will be the same for the different versions, but there will be small differences, e.g. native code preprocessor definitions in `Android.mk`, slight differences in some of the Java code, different output filenames.

Should I just set up separate projects, and use my `Android.mk` files and Eclipse's *Properties -> Java Build Path* to point at the shared code?

Comment: I don't think they have it in the Eclipse. I've heard they have it or going to have it in the new Android Studio.

Comment: I would "mavenize" the project and use some profiles.

Comment: This answer might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9206651/462285

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse CDT provides multiple configurations (try right click on project -> **Build Configurations**). But this only works for native projects, or for the C++ part of mixed projects, like the Android projects with **Native Support**.